# Inconsistent Composite Component clientId when using a MethodExpression attribute

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component

Hi suppose you have the following composite component:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
>
  <composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="action" targets="#{cc.clientId}:value"/>
  </composite:interface>

  <composite:implementation>
    <h1>clientId is: #{cc.clientId}</h1>
    <h:commandButton id="value" action="null" value="submit"/>
  </composite:implementation>

</html>
```

This composite component simply prints out the **clientId** now if I use this composite component as follows:

```
<h:form id="formID">
  <wui:test id="testID"/>
</h:form>
```

What I would expect to have as a result is:

**clientId is: formID:testID**

BUT what I really get is:

**clientId is: testID**

Now if I click on the button the form will be submitted and now the result is:

**clientId is: formID:testID**

What is causing the problem is the **action** attribute in the composite interface, if I remove it then the id is always **formID::testID**

Am I missing something?

---

**Update:**

I am using Mojarra **javax.faces-2.1.4.jar**

---

**Update:**

I created an issue for the Mojarra team [JAVASERVERFACES-2278](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/2282):

Comment: Interesting, I can reproduce this on Mojarra 2.1.4, but not in MyFaces 2.1.3. Even more, in MyFaces it's always `testID`. I'd also expect it to be `formID:testID` all the time, not sure why MyFaces is doing it differently. In any way, this is worth an issue report to the Mojarra guys.

Comment: I will wait one or two more days maybe someone knows something. if not I will post it for Mojarra guys.

Comment: Good you posted the issue. Note that the normal way would be using `targets="value"`. But that still don't solve the issue with `<h1>clientId is: #{cc.clientId}</h1>`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip of the targets attribute.