# Composite Component editableValueHolder inconsistency with Bean Validation

Tags: validation, jsf-2, composite-component

I have the following composite component:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
  xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite" 
>
<composite:interface>
  <composite:attribute name="value"/>
  <composite:editableValueHolder name="value" targets="#{cc.clientId}:value"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
  <h:inputText id="value" />
  <h:message for="#{cc.clientId}:value"/>
</composite:implementation>

</html>
```

And the following managed bean

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class TestMB {

    @NotNull
    private Date value;

    public String action1() {
        System.out.println("The value is: " + value);
        return null;
    }

    public Date getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Date value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

And the following custom converter:

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

@FacesConverter("myCustomConverter")
public class MyCustomConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String value) {
        if (value == null || "".equals(value)) {
            return null;
        }
        return new Date();
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return obj.toString();
    }
}
```

And the following test page:

```
<h:body>
  <h:form>
    Enter value: 
    <wui:test value="#{testMB.value}" id="myID">
      <f:converter converterId="myCustomConverter" for="value"/>
    </wui:test>
    <h:commandLink action="#{testMB.action1}" value="submit"/>
  </h:form>
</h:body>
```

When I run the web application and leave the text field empty and hit the submit button no validation errors are raised and I get the following on the Java console:

```
The value is: null
```

To make things more complicated, If I modify my composite component as follows (I added the value="#{cc.attrs.value}" to the h:inputText

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
  xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite" 
>
<composite:interface>
  <composite:attribute name="value"/>
  <composite:editableValueHolder name="value" targets="#{cc.clientId}:value"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
  <h:inputText id="value" value="#{cc.attrs.value}"/>
  <h:message for="#{cc.clientId}:value"/>
</composite:implementation>

</html>
```

And try again to submit the form when NO value is set, I don't get any validation errors displayed on the page, but I get the following warning in the console:

```
INFO: WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
sourceId=myID:value[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(may not be null), detail=(may not be null)]
```

Then if I try to re-submit the form again the action is submitted even if the field is empty. And I get the following in the console:

```
The value is: null
```

However if I remove the **id="myID"** everything is OK!

**Finally:** If I set prependId="false" on my form, everything is OK.

But I don't want to set prependId="false" and I do need to set an ID :(

Comment: Where does your `partNumber` in `StringUtils.isEmpty(partNumber)` come from? Can you post the full code of your `Converter` as well as your `StringUtils` class?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, when I debug the converter works fine, enters the (if) statement and returns null, but the validation is not triggered.

Comment: *"if I remove the `<f:validator>`"* don't you mean `<f:converter>`?

Comment: Yes another type: I guess I am too hungry :) ... its <f:converter>

Comment: This is odd. I can think of a cause where the inverse of the behaviour could happen, but not this. Are you sure that you didn't swap the described behaviours? Which JSF/JSR303 related `<context-param>`s do you all have in `web.xml`?

Comment: I figured out what is causing the problem, I will rephrase the whole question... I think its a bug.

Comment: @BalusC: I only have the javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE, and I am using Mojarra 2.1.4, and Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final

Comment: Ah well. You *actually* got an error message, it was just simply not shown in the view due to an issue related to composite components (which you didn't mention anything about in your initial question). This is more related to your other question then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706376/inconsistent-composite-component-clientid-when-using-a-methodexpression-attribut

Comment: Yeah my first post was a mess. And yes I think its clientId related problem, but I don't understand why if I re-submit the form again validation is ignored.